Need help on extract output from json file
I am new to python and i need some help to achive my output format.
i have response.json file output (getting this output from some other depended service.
Note: when i checked the type of this file its showing as list)
import json
results = json.load(open("response.text"))
print(type(results))
# <class 'list'>

The contents of results are:
[
  [
    "############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################",
    " 10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp",
    "############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################"
  ],
  [
    {
      "HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL": [
        "",
        "Source Address: 10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192",
        "Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.161.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.162.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.163.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.165.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.166.128.0/255.255.128.0,10.170.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.173.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.176.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.178.0.0/255.255.192.0,10.178.200.0/255.255.248.0,10.178.208.0/255.255.240.0,10.180.0.0/255.252.0.0,10.184.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.208.192.0/255.255.192.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.213.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.214.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.218.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.220.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.224.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.226.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.235.0.0/255.255.224.0,10.244.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.247.0.0/255.255.0.0",
        "Destination Port: 22,
        "Source Port: 0",
        "Protocol: tcp",
        "Application: ",
        "Wildcard: False",
        "Action: PERMIT"
      ]
    },
    {
      "HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL": [
        "",
        "Source Address: 10.0.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.10.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.18.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.44.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.161.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.162.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.173.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.180.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.182.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.186.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.188.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.218.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.219.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.226.128.0/255.255.255.192,10.227.130.192/255.255.255.192,10.244.132.128/255.255.255.192",
        "Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0",
        "Destination Port: 22,
        "Source Port: 0",
        "Protocol: tcp",
        "Application: ",
        "Wildcard: False",
        "Action: PERMIT"
      ]
    }
  ]
]


i want to get only output as below from the above response.json file

"############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################",
    " 10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp",
"############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################"

"HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL":
"Action: PERMIT"

"HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL"
"Action: PERMIT"


How to get output lile this ?
I tried it in below way
import json
from pprint import pprint

results = json.load(open("response.text"))

pprint(list(enumerate(results)))

for line in results:
     for l in line:
        pprint(l)


but output is cominng in this format

sivarama.krishna@sivaram-ltm3m98 hunter-gus-tools % python3 test.py
0
['############################## CHECKING FLOW '
 '####################################',
 ' 10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.212.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp',
 '############################## CHECKING FLOW '
 '####################################']
1
[{'HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM  FROM ACL': ['',
                            
                                             'Source Address: '
                                             '10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192',
                                             'Destination Address: '
                                             '10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.161.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.162.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.163.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.165.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.166.128.0/255.255.128.0,10.170.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.173.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.176.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.178.0.0/255.255.192.0,10.178.200.0/255.255.248.0,10.178.208.0/255.255.240.0,10.180.0.0/255.252.0.0,10.184.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.208.192.0/255.255.192.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.213.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.214.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.218.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.220.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.224.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.226.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.235.0.0/255.255.224.0,10.244.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.247.0.0/255.255.0.0',
                                             'Destination Port: '
                                             '22,
                                             'Source Port: 0',
                                             'Protocol: tcp',
                                             'Application: ',
                                             'Wildcard: False',
                                             'Action: PERMIT']},
 {'HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL  TO ACL': ['',

                                              'Source Address: '
                                              '10.0.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.10.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.18.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.44.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.161.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.162.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.173.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.180.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.182.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.186.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.188.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.218.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.219.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.226.128.0/255.255.255.192,10.227.130.192/255.255.255.192,10.244.132.128/255.255.255.192',
                                              'Destination Address: '
                                              '10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0',
                                              'Destination Port: '
                                              '22,
                                              'Source Port: 0',
                                              'Protocol: tcp',
                                              'Application: ',
                                              'Wildcard: False',
                                              'Action: PERMIT']}]


If the part of result that you want to print is in the first list in the result, then you can print it with "print(result[0][0])" .

Can you validate your posted source data. it is not valid json at the moment.

You're missing quotes at the end of "Destination Port: 22

The output you show can't be coming from the JSON you posted (even if the above is fixed).

And the output you show is also not possible, it has a missing quote in '22,. Please copy/paste instead of retyping.

if you have nested data then you may need nested for-loops to work with this. You already used for-loop to display index and item - so you should know that you can get first part from results[0], and it should gives you list with one element - so you need another [0] to get this element results[0][0]. Next you may also use type(item) to check if you have list or dict and use [0] (to see first element on list, or .keys() to see keys in dict, or .items() to see keys and values in dict. This way you can examine every level of nested data - to recognize parameters.

see also list(results[1].keys())[0] and list(results[2].keys())[0] and list(results[1].values())[0][-1], list(results[2].values())[0][-1]

I assumes that missing " in line "Destination Port: 22" is only typo and I add it in data.

Nested data may need nested for-loops to check structure.
data = [... your data ...]

for index, item in enumerate(data):
    print(f'[{index}]', 'type(item):', type(item))

    if isinstance(item, list):
        print(f'[{index}]', 'len(item):', len(item))
        for i in range(len(item)):
            print(f'[{index}][{i}]', '  :', item[i])

    if isinstance(item, dict):
        print(f'[{index}]', 'item.keys():', item.keys())
        for key in item:
            print(f'[{index}][{key}]', item[key])

which gives
[0] type(item): <class 'list'>
[0] len(item): 3
[0][0]   : ############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################
[0][1]   :  10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp
[0][2]   : ############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################
[1] type(item): <class 'list'>
[1] len(item): 2
[1][0]   : {'HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL': ['', 'Source Address: 10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192', 'Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.161.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.162.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.163.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.165.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.166.128.0/255.255.128.0,10.170.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.173.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.176.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.178.0.0/255.255.192.0,10.178.200.0/255.255.248.0,10.178.208.0/255.255.240.0,10.180.0.0/255.252.0.0,10.184.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.208.192.0/255.255.192.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.213.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.214.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.218.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.220.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.224.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.226.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.235.0.0/255.255.224.0,10.244.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.247.0.0/255.255.0.0', 'Destination Port: 22', 'Source Port: 0', 'Protocol: tcp', 'Application: ', 'Wildcard: False', 'Action: PERMIT']}
[1][1]   : {'HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL': ['', 'Source Address: 10.0.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.10.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.18.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.44.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.161.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.162.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.173.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.180.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.182.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.186.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.188.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.218.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.219.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.226.128.0/255.255.255.192,10.227.130.192/255.255.255.192,10.244.132.128/255.255.255.192', 'Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0', 'Destination Port: 22', 'Source Port: 0', 'Protocol: tcp', 'Application: ', 'Wildcard: False', 'Action: PERMIT']}

It may need another loops to check data[0] and data[1].
Normally I would use recursion but this time I make it manually.
For data[0] (which is list of strings) it may need
for index, item in enumerate(data[0]):
    #print(f'[{index}] type(item):', type(item))
    print(f'[{index}]', item)

which gives
[0] ############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################
[1]  10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp
[2] ############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################

So it needs to get data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2] - or simply get full data[0]
For data[1] (which is list of dicts) it may need
for item in data[1]:
    for key, val in item.items():
        print('key:', key)
        print('val:', val)
        print('val[-1]:', val[-1])

which gives
key: HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL
val: ['', 'Source Address: 10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192', 'Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.161.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.162.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.163.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.165.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.166.128.0/255.255.128.0,10.170.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.173.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.176.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.178.0.0/255.255.192.0,10.178.200.0/255.255.248.0,10.178.208.0/255.255.240.0,10.180.0.0/255.252.0.0,10.184.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.208.192.0/255.255.192.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.213.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.214.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.218.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.220.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.224.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.226.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.235.0.0/255.255.224.0,10.244.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.247.0.0/255.255.0.0', 'Destination Port: 22', 'Source Port: 0', 'Protocol: tcp', 'Application: ', 'Wildcard: False', 'Action: PERMIT']
val[-1]: Action: PERMIT
key: HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL
val: ['', 'Source Address: 10.0.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.10.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.18.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.44.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.161.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.162.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.173.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.180.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.182.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.186.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.188.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.218.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.219.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.226.128.0/255.255.255.192,10.227.130.192/255.255.255.192,10.244.132.128/255.255.255.192', 'Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0', 'Destination Port: 22', 'Source Port: 0', 'Protocol: tcp', 'Application: ', 'Wildcard: False', 'Action: PERMIT']
val[-1]: Action: PERMIT

So it needs to get all key, and val[-1].
Finally it gives me idea for code:
lines = data[0].copy()  # get all items 
lines.append("") # add empty line

for item in data[1]:
    for key, val in item.items():
        lines.append(key)
        lines.append(val[-1])        
        lines.append("") # add empty line
        
text = "\n".join(lines)     
print(text)

which gives
############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################
 10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp
############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################

HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL
Action: PERMIT

HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL
Action: PERMIT



Full code with data:
data = [
  [
    "############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################",
    " 10.211.131.19 [MUM] ---> 10.221.131.19 [DEL] on Port: 22, Protocol: tcp",
    "############################## CHECKING FLOW ####################################"
  ],
  [
    {
      "HUNTER OUTPUT FOR MUM FROM ACL": [
        "",
        "Source Address: 10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192",
        "Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.161.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.162.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.163.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.165.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.166.128.0/255.255.128.0,10.170.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.173.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.176.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.178.0.0/255.255.192.0,10.178.200.0/255.255.248.0,10.178.208.0/255.255.240.0,10.180.0.0/255.252.0.0,10.184.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.208.192.0/255.255.192.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.213.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.214.128.0/255.255.192.0,10.218.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.220.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.224.0.0/255.255.0.0,10.226.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.235.0.0/255.255.224.0,10.244.0.0/255.254.0.0,10.247.0.0/255.255.0.0",
        "Destination Port: 22",
        "Source Port: 0",
        "Protocol: tcp",
        "Application: ",
        "Wildcard: False",
        "Action: PERMIT"
      ]
    },
    {
      "HUNTER OUTPUT FOR DEL TO ACL": [
        "",
        "Source Address: 10.0.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.10.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.18.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.44.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.161.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.162.133.0/255.255.255.192,10.173.132.128/255.255.255.192,10.180.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.182.133.192/255.255.255.192,10.186.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.188.132.192/255.255.255.192,10.211.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.218.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.219.131.192/255.255.255.192,10.226.128.0/255.255.255.192,10.227.130.192/255.255.255.192,10.244.132.128/255.255.255.192",
        "Destination Address: 10.160.0.0/255.255.128.0,10.164.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.172.160.0/255.255.224.0,10.212.0.0/255.255.0.0",
        "Destination Port: 22",
        "Source Port: 0",
        "Protocol: tcp",
        "Application: ",
        "Wildcard: False",
        "Action: PERMIT"
      ]
    }
  ]
]

for index, item in enumerate(data):
    print(f'[{index}]', 'type(item):', type(item))
    if isinstance(item, list):
        print(f'[{index}]', 'len(item):', len(item))
        for i in range(len(item)):
            print(f'[{index}][{i}]', '  :', item[i])
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        print(f'[{index}]', 'item.keys():', item.keys())
        for key in item:
            print(f'[{index}][{key}]', item[key])

print('\n--- data[0] ---\n')

for index, item in enumerate(data[0]):
    #print(f'[{index}] type(item):', type(item))
    print(f'[{index}]', item)
    
#text = "\n".join(data[0])     
#print(text)

print('\n--- data[1] ---\n')

for item in data[1]:
    for key, val in item.items():
        print('key:', key)
        print('val:', val)
        print('val[-1]:', val[-1])
        
print('\n--- values ---\n')
        
lines = data[0].copy()
lines.append("") # empty line

for item in data[1]:
    for key, val in item.items():
        lines.append(key)
        lines.append(val[-1])        
        lines.append("") # empty line
        
text = "\n".join(lines)     
print(text)

